# Protocol Buffers - inconsistant serialization?

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, buffer, protocols

If this is a dumb question, I apologize, I'm running on almost no sleep.

I'm serializing a protocol buffer message in C++ and sending it over a TCP connection to a C# client.  Everything works approximately 75% of the time, however, about 25% of the time, I get an invalid serialization exception.

After a little poking around, I found that the byte array from the valid messages was different from the invalid messages.  It appears to consistently be the same byte over and over that is wrong.

I can post code if necessary, but am I missing something here?  Why would the C++ server not serialize an object the same every time?  (BTW, I hardcoded an object to test this.  To be sure the fields aren't changing.)

Here is the byte array from the clients point of view, after being sent through the socket.

```
8 162 1 18 21 84 87 32 86 101 110 100 105 110 103 32 68 101 109 111 32 83 116 111 114 101 24 176 32 132 131 186 141 5 40 2 48 42 56 2 - bad serialization

8 162 1 18 21 84 87 32 86 101 110 100 105 110 103 32 68 101 109 111 32 83 116 111 114 101 24   7 32 132 131 186 141 5 40 2 48 42 56 2 - good serialization

8 162 1 18 21 84 87 32 86 101 110 100 105 110 103 32 68 101 109 111 32 83 116 111 114 101 24 128 32 132 131 186 141 5 40 2 48 42 56 2 - bad serialization

8 162 1 18 21 84 87 32 86 101 110 100 105 110 103 32 68 101 109 111 32 83 116 111 114 101 24 216 32 132 131 186 141 5 40 2 48 42 56 2 - bad serialization

8 162 1 18 21 84 87 32 86 101 110 100 105 110 103 32 68 101 109 111 32 83 116 111 114 101 24   0 32 132 131 186 141 5 40 2 48 42 56 2 - good serialization

8 162 1 18 21 84 87 32 86 101 110 100 105 110 103 32 68 101 109 111 32 83 116 111 114 101 24 255 32 132 131 186 141 5 40 2 48 42 56 2 - bad serialization
```

Notice that the 13th byte from the end is different?  I also added which ones where successfully serialized.  Thanks.

UPDATE - I'm posting my C# client code as the problem most likely lies on this end.  I also have wrapped the generated proto objects so your going to have to take my word for it that my serialization functions are working correctly.  ( I'm 100% sure they are. )

```
 private List<byte> LockNetworkStream(ref System.IO.Stream clientStream, byte[] data)
        {
            List<byte> completeMessage = new List<byte>();

            try
            {
                lock (clientStream)
                {
                    byte[] bufferLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
                    clientStream.ReadTimeout = 10000;

                    clientStream.Write(bufferLength, 0, bufferLength.Length);
                    clientStream.Flush();

                    clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    clientStream.Flush();

                    byte[] messageLength = new byte[4];
                    int bytesRead = 0;

                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(messageLength, 0, 4);
                    int messageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(messageLength, 0);
                    if (messageSize > 0)
                    {
                        int totalBytesRead = 0;
                        byte[] message = new byte[messageSize];                        
                        while (totalBytesRead < messageSize)
                        {
                            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, messageSize - totalBytesRead);
                            if (bytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] temp = new byte[bytesRead];
                                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                                {
                                    temp[i] = message[i];
                                }

                                completeMessage.AddRange(temp);
                                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        clientStream.Flush();
                    }
                }  
            }
            catch (StokedTcpException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                if (reconnectAttempts < 3)
                {
                    Reconnect();
                    return LockNetworkStream(ref clientStream, data);   
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to connect.  Please check your internet connection or firewall config");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return completeMessage;
        }

        public byte[] Communicate(byte[] data, ref TcpClient client)
        {
            byte[] bufferLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
            System.IO.Stream clientStream = null;
            lock (client)
            {
                clientStream = client.GetStream();
            }            

            List<byte> completeMessage = LockNetworkStream(ref clientStream, data);

            ServerFunctionResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = ServerFunctionResponse.Deserialize(completeMessage.ToArray());
                deserializeAttempts = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Unable to deserialize server response: " + ex.Message);
            }

            if (response.IsException)
            {
                StokedTcpException exception = StokedTcpException.Deserialize(response.Data);
                throw exception;
            }

            return response.Data;            
        }
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to show at least the message definition from `.proto`.

Comment: By the way, how are you obtaining this data? Did you get it directly from the server? I mean if it was sent over the network it could get broken there.

Comment: Seems to be inevitable to post some code. Is there any multithread access to your buffer on the server side?

Comment: There is, however, each client runs within it's own thread and there are not any other threads being created.